# Can Samba close a single user session coming from a shared host?

Tags: samba, samba4

If I want to close a user session on a Samba server, the `smbcontrol close-share` and `smbcontrol kill-client-ip` commands are available to achieve this. However when dealing with a shared client (a Windows Terminal Server for example) these commands close the session of all users on that client.

Is it possible to *close the session of only one user if that session comes from a shared host*? I've looked at the `smbcontrol`, `samba-tool` and `net` utilities, and although `net rap session` looked promising, it doesn't seem to work. I also tried `net rpc file CLOSE`, but that too doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: yes, it can.

It is possible to list the open files with the command: `net rpc file -U $user`. The resulting list includes a *FileId* as first field. A specific file can be closed by using its FileId in this command: `net rpc file close $fileid -U $user`

Note that the $user used to connect needs to have the *SeDiskOperatorPrivilege* for the close command to work!

Answer (score 1):

This post might help you. there are several answers so have a look and let us know if anything was helpful.
[1]: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72e66e9c-f55f-47ee-af92-20db0a2daacc/closing-smb-session-on-windows-client

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to close the session server-side, not client-side, so I'm looking for a linux/samba command to do this.

Comment: I believe you can kill the login of that user I reckon well or reach out to that user to close the connection on their end.